# Unable to get eslint working in Atom Editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm totally lost at this point on how to get ESLint to install and function using Atom. So I'm going to post a step by step and would be really awesome if someone could help be get this working.

- Atom: 1.19.5
- Atom, linter 2.2.0
- Atom, linter-eslint 8.2.1

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the Atom plugins and have disabled all other plugins besides those in Core and the 2 linters.

- `npm list -g --depth=0`

All Global Installs:

```
├── create-react-app@1.0.4
├── create-react-native-app@1.0.0
├── eslint@4.6.1
├── express-generator@4.14.1
├── json-server@0.9.5
├── mocha@3.2.0
├── nodemon@1.11.0
├── npm@3.10.10
├── pushstate-server@2.2.1
├── react-native-cli@2.0.1
├── react-vr-cli@0.3.5
├── webpack@2.2.1
├── webpack-dev-server@2.3.0
└── yarn@0.21.3
```

These are the attempted steps I've done to get eslint to work in my Atom project:

- `npm install -g eslint`
- `cd /into/project`
- `eslint --init`
- `? How would you like to configure ESLint? > User a popular style guide`
- `? Which style guide do you want to follow? >Airbnb`
- `? Do you use React? > y`
- `? What format do you want your config file to be in? > JSON`
- Delete `/node_modules`
- `npm install`

  /project
    /node_modules
    .eslintrc.json
    index.js
    package.json

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lint-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

This is just a file trying to get some type of results from `eslint`

**Errors**

[Linter] Error running ESLint (Open developer console)

`Configuration for rule "jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content" is invalid: Value "[object Object]" no (or more than one) schemas match.`

- So went to [eslint-plugin-jsx #168](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/168)

No errors are appearing in the Atom developer console. But also nothing is happening with the Linter in the Atom editor. I can type gibberish and nothing happens.

**Running Debug**

- `DEBUG=eslint:* eslint .`

Debug results:

```
Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'
Referenced from: /Users/user/development/lint-test/.eslintrc.json
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'
Referenced from: /Users/user/development/lint-test/.eslintrc.json
at ModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
at resolve (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:515:25)
at load (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:584:26)
at configExtends.reduceRight.e (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:421:36)
at Array.reduceRight (native)
at applyExtends (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:403:28)
at loadFromDisk (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:556:22)
at Object.load (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:592:20)
at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:226:44)
at Config.getConfigHierarchy (/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:180:43)
```

At this point I'm assuming it's trying to read from the global not local

- [eslint eslint-config-airbnb error #465](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/465)
- updated `.eslintrc.json` to `"extends": "eslint-config-airbnb",`

Now again nothing is happening, run debug again

- `DEBUG=eslint:* eslint .`

Still can't find the module

- Try suggestions in [Configuring Atom editor with eslint](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2016/08/14/configuring-atom-with-eslint.html)

At this point I'm still running into `Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'`

- Followed [npm eslint-config-airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb)
- ran all the commands

**New local package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^4.6.1",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0"
}
```

- `npm install -g eslint-config-airbnb`

**New Global Modules**

```
├── create-react-app@1.0.4
├── create-react-native-app@1.0.0
├── eslint@4.6.1
├── eslint-config-airbnb@15.1.0
├── eslint-plugin-import@2.7.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.0.2
├── eslint-plugin-react@7.3.0
├── express-generator@4.14.1
├── install-peerdeps@1.1.3
├── json-server@0.9.5
├── mocha@3.2.0
├── nodemon@1.11.0
├── npm@3.10.10
├── pushstate-server@2.2.1
├── react-native-cli@2.0.1
├── react-vr-cli@0.3.5
├── webpack@2.2.1
├── webpack-dev-server@2.3.0
└── yarn@0.21.3
```

So now I can run `DEBUG=eslint:* eslint .` and can get some results. However nothing ever runs in Atom.

Results:

```
/Users/user/development/lint-test/index.js
  1:1   error  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/href-no-hash' was not found  jsx-a11y/href-no-hash
  1:7   error  'config' is assigned a value but never used                no-unused-vars
  1:24  error  Unable to resolve path to module '../something'            import/no-unresolved
  1:39  error  Missing semicolon                                          semi

✖ 4 problems (4 errors, 0 warnings)
  1 error, 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

At this point I'm out of ideas on how to get Atom to actually work with eslint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without digging into the issue and finding specific point of failure I decided on a fresh start.

- Delete global node modules.
- Delete all NON core Atom plugins AND themes.
- uninstall Atom.
- reinstall Atom.
- install ESLint and supporting dependencies only.

Doing that I was able to run ESLint with no issues. My assumption in all of this is there was a conflict in a plugin or theme. From there installing my core tool plugins was successful.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the setting "Use global ESLint installation" in linter-eslint of ATOM will make it correct